# How to theoretically estimate the waiting time of a spin lock?

Tags: math, concurrency, locking, theory, spinlock

Suppose I have N processes executing the following code:

```
while(True){
    try_lock(global_lock)
    # Run T_1 time in the critical zone
    unlock(global_lock)
    # Run T_2 time outside the critical zone
}
```

That is, each process repeatedly executes the following process: lock -> run T_1 time -> unlock -> run T_2 time, assuming that the execution time of try_lock() and unlock() is not considered, and assuming that T_2 > T_1.

How to calculate the average waiting time for obtaining the spinlock of each process ? The result should be a function of the number of processes N, the time-consuming of the critical zone T_1  and the one of the non-critical zone T_2:  f(N,T_1,T_2).

For the case of N=2, my reasoning is as follows:

```
P1 |--T_1--|---T_2---|--T_1--|---T_2---|--T_1--| ...

P2 |--wait-|--T_1--|---T_2---|--T_1--|---T_2---| ...
```

So the average waiting time is 0

But for the case of N>2, I don’t know how to construct it through mind experiments, it may require theoretical calculations

Comment: This is a queueing theory problem. Much of queuing theory focuses on cases where T1 and T2 are not constants but have some random variation (which tends to match the real world). Is it safe to assume that T1 and T2 are random also in your case?

Comment: @Joni Thank you for your reply. Of course it can be assumed. In fact, I set T1 and T2 as constants because I thought it would simplify the problem. It would be better if the distribution of T1 and T2 were also taken into consideration.